# What do I need to do to install and run Code Sourcery on an x86 64-bit Windows host system?

Tags: windows-7, compiler-construction, 64-bit, codesourcery

I have seen this question asked for a Linux host system but not for Windows.

I have a Windows 7 64-bit host system.  I am running into a 32 bit issue I think and I see this vague phrase in the Code Sourcery documentation.

"Therefore, even when running on a 64-bit host system, Sourcery CodeBench requires 32-bit host libraries. Consult your operating system documentation for more information about obtaining these libraries."

I can't find any documentation because I don't know what "these" libraries are.

Thanks,
Seth M King

Comment: As a CodeSourcery employee, I apologize for the vagueness of that documentation, and I'll let the right people know we need to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is really only for Linux users; a lot of Linux distributions don't include the basic system libraries (the equivalent of the stuff in `c:\Windows\System`) needed to run 32-bit applications.

Windows includes everything that's needed as far as this is concerned.